# Android switch in listview flipping bij scrolling

Tags: android, listview, switch-statement

I'm making a listview with Switch in each row. When I put the first item to **ON** and I scroll down, the the 7th row switch is going **ON** and the first one on is going **OFF**. How can this happen?

Base adapter:

```
public class QuestionsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private List<QuestionModel> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private int Icounter = 1;
    private DecimalFormat f;

    public QuestionsAdapter(Activity a, List<QuestionModel> d) {
        f = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_form, null);

        TextView tvQuest = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvQuest);

        Switch switch1 = (Switch) vi.findViewById(R.id.activeButton);

        tvQuest.setText(data.get(position).getKey());   
        Icounter++;
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Declaring the listview

```
questionList = new ArrayList<QuestionModel>();
questionAdapter = new QuestionsAdapter(ShopVisit.this, questionList);
lvQuestion.setAdapter(questionAdapter);
```

Listview item view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lvRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/dashboard_button"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvQuest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Question"
            android:textColor="@color/dimmed_text_2"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
     <Switch
        android:id="@+id/activeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" /></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please post the Turn on and off logic

you see when your trying to change the list you need to get position of the clicked switch and then apply off and on logic on that position
if your having doubt then print the position just for checking that your getting correct position or not

another way is you add one arraylist and change 0 to 1 when specific position clicked and call
baseadapaterclassobject.notifydatasetchanged() method.

and add one line in getview method if(arraylist.get(position) == 1) turn switch on !!